# What's the best approach to grow a big horn out of a creature head?

Tags: animation

My creature needs to have a horn grow out of its head with a smooth animation. Preferably there should be no seams between the horn and the head. Imagine there is a smooth surface and the horn will smoothly grow out from there. The horn is somewhat long and not a simple shape, so I assume shape keys are not the best approach. Do you have any suggestions?

The base model will be something like this:

[image]

And there should be horn growing out like this:

[image]

Comment: Hello, do you have some reference images of the style and shape?

Comment: Hi! the base model will be something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xptrle9vj17ftek/Frogolotls1.png?dl=0

and there should be horn growing out like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gbm95e4esu01ga/horn.png?dl=0

Comment: I may be wrong but It seems doable with shape keys

Comment: Another option is an armature with scaled and rotated bones to make the horns grow and expand.

Comment: I also recommend the shape keys. Try to model the tentacles first as the original shape, than push and smooth them into the head as a shape key.

Comment: @Blunder Thanks! Do you know a tutorial that's similar to this effect?

Comment: @moonboots Ffeller, Thanks! I will test it with the shape keys. I thought since I am doing sculpting in Zbrush, I was looking for another way. Also, how should I think about with UVs and textures? Do they kind of blend in and out between the shapes and use keyframes in the shader mix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shape keys. Create your horns, duplicate to have a shrinkwrap object, modify the topology to have some inner circles like that, use the *Shrinkwrap* modifier to make the mesh stick to the original horn shape, use a *Smooth* modifier to smooth the topology, apply the modifiers:

[image]

Create a basic shape key and a second one:

[image]

Once animated it gives that (the third branch can appear later, with a new shape key):

[image]